# MKOverlayRenderer gets cut off when rendering MKOverlay but fixed by zooming out

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-graphics, mkoverlay

I'm new to iOS development and I'm struggling with porting some code from iOS6 involving the use of `MKOverlay`.

When the overlay radius or coordinate change, the renderer should update the display accordingly in real time.

This part works, but if I drag the overlay too much, it reaches some boundary and the rendering gets cut off. I can't find any documentation or help on this behavior.

In the `CircleOverlayRenderer` class:

```
- (id)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];
    if (self) {
        CircleZone *bOverlay = (CircleZone *)overlay;
        [RACObserve(bOverlay, coordinate) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }];
        [RACObserve(bOverlay, radius) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:[self.overlay boundingMapRect]];

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, colorSpace);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);

    CGContextSetFillColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);

    // outline
    {
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.8);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    }

    // red
    {
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
        CGRect ellipseRect = CGRectInset(rect, 0.01 * rect.size.width / 2, 0.01 * rect.size.height / 2);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, ellipseRect);
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(cox);
}
```

In the `CircleOverlay` class:

```
- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
{
    MKMapPoint center = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.coordinate);
    double mapPointsPerMeter = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(self.coordinate.latitude);
    double mapPointsRadius = _radius * mapPointsPerMeter;

    return MKMapRectMake(center.x - mapPointsRadius, center.y - mapPointsRadius,
                         mapPointsRadius * 2.0, mapPointsRadius * 2.0);
}
```

Here are some screen shots of the problem I'm seeing:

Problem when dragging overlay too much:
[image: Problem when dragging overlay too much]

Problem when changing the radius:
[image: Problem when changing the radius]

The problem does go away if I keep zooming the map out. After the map tiles refresh, the overlay no longer gets cut off...

If anyone had a similar problem, please help me, it's driving me crazy!

Comment: This answer works (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614644/6753453), but needs rotation management

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `radius` example, it makes me suspect the `boundingMapRect`, given how its cropping. Looking at the `boundingMapRect` implementation, the reliance upon `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude` (esp when you're looking at a large region) is worrying. That function is useful if you are, for example, trying to figure out where a coordinate 10 meters from some other coordinate, but when looking at really large spans, it doesn't always work out well.

I might, instead, suggest something that gets the `MKCoordinateRegion` of where the circle is, and then convert that to `MKMapRect`. A simplistic implementation might look like:

```
- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.coordinate, _radius * 2, _radius * 2);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperLeftCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerRightCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);

    MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperLeftCoordinate);
    MKMapPoint lowerRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerRightCoordinate);

    return MKMapRectMake(MIN(upperLeft.x, lowerRight.x),
                         MIN(upperLeft.y, lowerRight.y),
                         ABS(upperLeft.x - lowerRight.x),
                         ABS(upperLeft.y - lowerRight.y));
}
```

You'll have to tweak with this to make sure it gracefully handles crossing of the 180th meridian and when the circle encompasses the north pole, but it illustrates the basic idea: Get `MKCoordinateRegion` for the circle and then convert that to `MKMapRect`.

Comment: I thought the clipping was impacted by the `boundingMapRect` originally, but actually changing the `boundingMapRect` only changes the size of the circle. Unfortunately, I'm only limited to 2 links in my question, but dragging the overlay actually results in clipping along the same map tiles. Thanks for letting me know about the inaccurancy of `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude` but the clipping varies greatly at different zoom scales, seems to be scale independent. (The more zoomed it is, it clips at smaller radius)

Comment: I still contend that an incorrect `boundingMapRect` (either wrong size during a resize or the wrong place during a drag) will manifest itself precisely as you illustrate in your question. Note, if the `boundingMapRect` is too small, it can manifest itself as not rendering the entire overlay, but with straight-edged cropping, but not necessarily so. Maps use rectangular tiles, so it uses the `boundingMapRect` to know which tiles need to be re-rendered. It's either the wrong size or is in the wrong place (or both).

Comment: @kudos - Your images look like the map is being rendered during the gesture, but the `boundingMapRect` is perhaps returning an out-dated value. Or you might need to make sure that `boundingMapRect` calculates the current `MKMapRect`, but returns the union of that and of all previous calculated values throughout the gesture. But I would hesitate to draw any conclusions based upon the overlay being rendered correctly when you subsequently zoom out on the map. It could be the tiles are larger. It could be a lot of things. It's hard to say without a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I gave up on using MKOverlay, and I got around the issue by using `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKOverlayRenderer`. It works nearly the same way, but does not cull other overlays when they intersect. Yes, I believe you are right on your last comment. An additional behavior I witnessed is calling `addOverlay` and `removeOverlay` fixes the problem, but produces a flickering each time the overlay is added. It seems the gesture does not trigger a rerendering of all map tiles, but only the ones it was touching originally when added using the `addOverlay` call.